# Any good plugin to combine svg into one spritesheet with output css generation (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, gulp, sprite

Does anybody use svg as sprites in webpack projects?
When i was using gulp - I used this plugin: https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite

is there any good webpack replacement? i tried a lot of webpack solutions, but none of them worked with ready css output generation (like generated .svg + .css with all dimensions, positions etc)

or maybe somebody have a custom solution?

with concat svg files & generating style file

Comment: not sure if youthat is what you mean :  http://pavliko.github.io/postcss-svg/#examples

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora thanks, but not exactly - itsn't replacing url vars